# Is this sufficient proof to show that $f^2$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, singularity

I want to prove that if f has an essential singularity at $z_0$ then $f^2$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$ as well.

I know that if f has an essential singularity at $z_0$ then f can be represented as $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ where $a_n \neq0$ for an infinite set on which $n<0$.

I also know that if one wants to multiply a series the following is true $\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \right)   \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$.

So to prove what I mentioned can I just say that

$(f(z))^2=(\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n)(\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}(z-z_0)^n=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}c_n(z-z_0)^n.$

Where $c_n=|a_n|^2$ and then note if $a_n \neq0 \forall n<0 \Rightarrow c_n \neq0 \forall n<0$ and so $f^2$ also has an essential singularity at $z_0$ ?

Comment: Since there are $n < 0$ with $a_n \neq 0$, the coefficients of $f^2$ are not $\sum_{k = 0}^n a_k a_{n-k}$ but $\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} a_k a_{n-k}$. If we call the coefficients $c_n$, then we do _not_ have $c_n = \lvert a_n\rvert^2$ except in very special situations. The Casorati-Weierstraß theorem can be used in a simple proof.

Comment: we haven't done the Casorati-weierstrass Theorem in class unfortunately.

Comment: What do you know about the behaviour of holomorphic functions near isolated singularities?

Comment: @DanielFischer all I really know is that a singularity is  a point at which a function is not defined, where it fails to be well-behaved in some particular way, such as differentiability

Comment: Do you know that an isolated singularity is always either removable, or a pole, or essential, and these are mutually exclusive?

Comment: @DanielFischer  yes, I did know this.

Comment: Good. Do you know characterisations of removable singularities and of poles?

Comment: @DanielFischer as in we characterise an essential pole as one that can be represented as $f(z)=\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$ where $a_n \neq 0$ for an infinite set on which n<0 etc... ? then yes I am also familiar with this .

Comment: I meant characterisations in terms of the values the function attains near the singularity, not in terms of the Laurent series. It's probably possible to show that an essential isolated singularity of $f$ is also one of $f^2$ via calculations on the Laurent series, that's much harder than getting the result from the mapping behaviour of the function near an isolated singularity.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm afraid the classifications were given in terms of the Laurent series in class , not the mappings. So it looks like the more difficult route is the expected one :/